# Querying one-to-one in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I have two models city and business.I have to perform below queries

1. Find Business by city name.
2. Find Top 10 cities which have the maximum business.

Here is the models

Business

```
class Business extends \Eloquent 
{
   protected $fillable = [
       'business_type',
       'first_name',
       'last_name',
       'email',
       'password',
       'designation_id',
       'name',
       'description',
       'portfolio_id',
       'image',
       'city_id',
       'package_id',
       'group_tag_id'
   ];

   public function city()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('City');
   }
}
```

City

```
class City extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'district_id'];
    public function business()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Business');
    }
}
```

So How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can fetch this by this ways :

Find Top 10 cities which have the maximum business:

```
$city = City::with('business')->get()->sortBy(function($query) {
                                        return $query->business->count();
                                    }, SORT_REGULAR, true)
                        ->take(10);
```

Find Business by city name.

```
Business::whereHas('city', function ($q) {
   $q->where('name', 'like', 'search_string');//name is the city_name as per your attributes name
})->get();
```

Comment: Where should i put the orderBy method if i want to order the city by name?

Comment: after $q->where('name', 'like', 'search_string'); add
 $q->orderBy('name','ASC');

Comment: i want to ordered the top 10 cities

Comment: did you mean 'Find Top 10 cities which have the maximum business order by city name'